# An AppScript which fetch metadata from a list of URLs

Tags: google-apps-script, metadata, meta-tags

Thank you for this great forum. I am a very very beginner in coding.

My issue: I have a column of hundreds URLs, and I want to automatically query their metatags to get their: "title", "description", "keywords" and "logo".

I don't manage to write a good script to do it (knowing that I will copy this script in Google Sheet): it is difficult to deal with the various x-path that exist within websites.

Many thanks in advance for your help
Best

I tried some scripts,
and more basically also tested a Google Sheet function (importxml).
But both only work 1 out 5 times...

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I tried:

```
function removeOldMetaDataFromSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().find().forEach(e => e.remove());//removes meta data in the range
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Complete');
}

function addRangeMetaData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    sh.getRange(String(i + 1) + ':' + String(i + 1)).addDeveloperMetadata('row' + String(i));
    if (i == 0) {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let l = getColumnLetters(j+1);
        sh.getRange(l + ':' + l).addDeveloperMetadata('col' + String(j));
      });
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Complete');
}

function displayMetaDataForARange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var v = rg.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().find();
  let md = [];
  v.forEach(e => {
    let obj = {};
    obj['key'] = e.getKey();
    obj['value'] = e.getValue();
    obj['visibility'] = e.getVisibility();
    if (e.getKey().toString().slice(0, 3) == 'row') {
      obj['A1'] = e.getLocation().getRow().getA1Notation();
      let w = getRowWidth(e.getLocation().getRow().getRow(), sh, ss);
      obj['rowWidth'] = w;
      obj['rowvalues'] = e.getLocation().getRow().getValues().flat().filter((r, i) => i < w).join(',');
    } else {
      obj['A1'] = e.getLocation().getColumn().getA1Notation();
      let h = getColumnHeight(e.getLocation().getColumn().getColumn(), sh, ss);
      obj['colheight'] = h;
      obj['colvalues'] = e.getLocation().getColumn().getValues().flat().filter((c, i) => i < h).join(',');
    }
    obj['id'] = e.getId();
    md.push(obj);
    //e.remove();
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea rows="25" cols="150">' + JSON.stringify(md) + '</textarea>').setWidth(1200).setHeight(600), 'Meta Data');
}

function getMetaDataForARangeById() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  let resp = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Search for Meta Data by Id', 'Enter Id', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  let o;
  if (resp.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let id = resp.getResponseText();
    let r = rg.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().withId(id).find();
    r.forEach(e => {
      if (e.getLocation().getLocationType() == SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.ROW) {
        o = e.getLocation().getRow().getValues().flat().filter(e => e).join();
      } else if (e.getLocation().getLocationType() == SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.COLUMN) {
        o = e.getLocation().getColumn().getValues().flat().filter(e => e).join(',');
      }
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea row="30" cols="120">' + o + '</textarea>').setWidth(800).setHeight(400), 'Results');
  }
}

function getMetaDataForARangeByKey() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  let resp = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Search for Meta Data by Key', 'Enter Key', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  let o;
  let s;
  if (resp.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let key = resp.getResponseText();
    let r = rg.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().withKey(key).find();
    r.forEach(e => {
      if (e.getLocation().getLocationType() == SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.ROW) {
        let row = e.getLocation().getRow().getRow();
        let w = getRowWidth(row, sh, ss);
        o = e.getLocation().getRow().getValues().flat().filter((e, i) => i < w).join(', ');
        s = `row: ${row} values: ${o}`;
      } else if (e.getLocation().getLocationType() == SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.COLUMN) {
        let col = e.getLocation().getColumn().getColumn();
        let h = getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss);
        o = e.getLocation().getColumn().getValues().flat().filter((e, i) => i < h).join(', ');
        s = `col: ${col} values: ${o}`;
      }
    });
    s = (s)?s:'No Such Key Found: ' + key;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(300).setHeight(150), 'Results');
  }
}

function getColumnLetters(colnum) {
  const a1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, colnum).getA1Notation();
  return a1.slice(0, a1.indexOf(/\d+/));
}

function UsedToBeAnonEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  let col = sh.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey('cb1').find()[0].getLocation().getColumn().getColumn();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == col && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE" ) {
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.range.offset(0,1).getValue() + 1);
  }
}

function setupOnEditMetaData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const l = getColumnLetters(sh.getLastColumn(), sh, ss);
  const rg = sh.getRange(l + ':' + l);
  rg.addDeveloperMetadata('cb1');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Complete');
}

function getCheckBoxColumn(key='cb1') {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let col = sh.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey('cb1').find()[0].getLocation().getColumn().getColumn();
  let s = getColumnLetters(col);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s),'Checkbox Column');
}

function addingmetadatatosomesheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh, i) => {
    if (sh.getName().match(/^Sheet\d{1,}/)) {
      sh.addDeveloperMetadata('shidx', i + 1);
    }
  });
}

function findSheetMetaData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    let v = sh.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey('shidx').find();
    if (v && v.length > 0) {
      v.forEach(e => {
        Logger.log(`SheetName: ${sh.getName()} Metadata: ${e.getValue()}`);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Waou ! Impressive, thanks a lot !